# images attached in MailJob - Android studio

Tags: java, android, email

I implemented a MailJob class to send email and it works fine. I need also to send attached images but it does not works.

This is the code I implemented

```
 class MailJob extends AsyncTask<MailJob.Mail,Void,Void> {
private final String user;
private final String pass;


public MailJob(String user, String pass) {
    super();
    this.user=user;
    this.pass=pass;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Mail... mails) {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
                }
            });
    for (Mail mail:mails) {

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mail.from));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(mail.to));
            message.setSubject(mail.subject);
            message.setText(mail.content);

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);


        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            Log.d("MailJob", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static class Mail{
    private final String subject;
    private final String content;
    private final String from;
    private final String to;
    private final Uri camino;


    public Mail(String from, String to, String subject, String content, Uri camino){
        this.subject=subject;
        this.content=content;
        this.from=from;
        this.to=to;
        this.camino=camino;
    }
}
```

To send attached images I implement the following but I get this output: **D/MailJob: IOException while sending message**

```
class MailJob extends AsyncTask<MailJob.Mail,Void,Void> {
private final String user;
private final String pass;


public MailJob(String user, String pass) {
    super();
    this.user=user;
    this.pass=pass;
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Mail... mails) {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
            new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(user, pass);
                }
            });
    for (Mail mail:mails) {

        try {

            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mail.from));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                    InternetAddress.parse(mail.to));
            message.setSubject(mail.subject);
            message.setText(mail.content);


            // Create the message part
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            // Now set the actual message
            messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");

            // Create a multipar message
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            // Set text message part
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Part two is attachment
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
           // String filename = ;
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(String.valueOf(mail.camino));
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName("imagen");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);


            // Send the complete message parts
            message.setContent(multipart);

            // Send message
            Transport.send(message);


        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            Log.d("MailJob", e.getMessage());
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public static class Mail{
    private final String subject;
    private final String content;
    private final String from;
    private final String to;
    private final Uri camino;


    public Mail(String from, String to, String subject, String content, Uri camino){
        this.subject=subject;
        this.content=content;
        this.from=from;
        this.to=to;
        this.camino=camino;
    }
}
```

Can anyone figure out what the problem is?

The Manifest has this permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gmail.permission.READ_GMAIL" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gm.permission.READ_GMAIL" />
```

What I get is :

```
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: external/images/media/4176/20200513_190645.jpg (No such file or directory)
```

I get the path and file with this:

```
 private void openGallery(){
    Intent gallery = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
    startActivityForResult(gallery, PICK_IMAGE);
}

  @Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
        imageUri = data.getData();
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContext().getContentResolver(), imageUri);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mg.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        a.add(bitmap);

    }
}
```

So, Uri.getPath()is the path and the datafile is getFileName(imageUri):

```
 public String getFileName(Uri uri) {
    String result = null;
    if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
        Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    if (result == null) {
        result = uri.getPath();
        int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (cut != -1) {
            result = result.substring(cut + 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The Logcat:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: IOException while sending message;
  nested exception is:
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/4176/20200505_103438.jpg (No such file or directory)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1290)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:255)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)
    at com.example.operacioneschecklist.MailJob.doInBackground(MailJob.java:87)
    at com.example.operacioneschecklist.MailJob.doInBackground(MailJob.java:24)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
 Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /external/images/media/4176/20200505_103438.jpg (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:231)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:165)
    at javax.activation.FileDataSource.getInputStream(FileDataSource.java:110)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:318)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1645)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:961)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart.writeTo(MimeMultipart.java:553)
    at com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed.writeTo(multipart_mixed.java:81)
    at javax.activation.ObjectDataContentHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:900)
    at javax.activation.DataHandler.writeTo(DataHandler.java:330)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart.writeTo(MimeBodyPart.java:1645)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.writeTo(MimeMessage.java:1850)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendMessage(SMTPTransport.java:1241)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:255) 
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124) 
    at com.example.operacioneschecklist.MailJob.doInBackground(MailJob.java:87) 
    at com.example.operacioneschecklist.MailJob.doInBackground(MailJob.java:24) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:245) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

Comment: You will have better luck if you post the entire stack trace, not just the error line.

Comment: D/MailJob: IOException while sending message

Comment: Replace `Log.d("MailJob", e.getMessage());` with `Log.e("MailJob", "Exception sending mail", e);`. Then examine the entire stack trace and consider adding it to your question.

Comment: What I get is this: java.io.FileNotFoundException: external/images/media/4176/20200513_190645.jpg (No such file or directory). How I get the path and filename is in the code

Comment: We still do not have a full stack trace. My guess is that your problem lies in `DataSource source = new FileDataSource(String.valueOf(mail.camino))`, where `mail.camino` is returning the value shown in your error. You will need to determine where that `camino` value is coming from. It is not a valid filesystem path. My guess is that you are treating a `Uri` as if it were a file.

Comment: But Ii consider the file as: Uri.getPath()/getFileName(Uri), that's the file

Comment: A `Uri` is not a file. `getPath()` only has meaning for a `Uri` if the scheme of the `Uri` is `file`. `ACTION_PICK` is unlikely to return such a `Uri` on modern versions of Android.

Comment: But I set the image path that I found in android galery an it does not work either.